# Problema com $_SESSION com $_GET exibindo na tabela resultado inesperado

Tags: php

```
<?php 

    session_start();

    if(isset($_GET['nome'])){

        $_SESSION['lista'][] = $_GET['nome'];
        $_SESSION['lista'][] = $_GET['telefone'];
        $_SESSION['lista'][] = $_GET['email'];

    }

    $lista = array();

    if(isset($_SESSION['lista'])){

        $lista = $_SESSION['lista'];


    }

?>
```

...

```
        <table style="width:100%" border="3">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Telefone</th>
                    <th>E-Mail</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <?php foreach($lista as $lis): ?>
                    <tr>

                        <td><?=$lis?></td>
                        <td><?=$lis?></td>
                        <td><?=$lis?></td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>


        </table>
```

...

Na hora de exibir na tabela uma linha é ocupada por nomes, e a linha seguinte por telefones, como posso resolver isso de forma que uma linha tenha nome, telefone e e-mail?

Comment: Conhece o [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php) do PHP?

Comment: Utilize o botão [edit] para adicionar mais informações a pergunta.

Comment: Sim, estou usando o foreach, o problema é naquele trecho de código, ao passar pro array a $_SESSION, que não estou sabendo fazer, quem puder ajudar com código agradeço.

Comment: Que trecho de código?

Comment: Sim, mas a minha dúvida é como armazenar três variáveis, nome, telefone e e-mail, em uma $_SESSION, e depois guardar e um array e exibir com foreach na tabela. Alguém pode ajudar ?

Comment: Você já está fazendo isso. Qual é o problema? Qual é o código que usa o `foreach`? Edite a pergunta e coloque-o.

Comment: Editei, colocando a parte do foreach

Comment: Serão vários nomes, telefones e e-mail armazenados na sessão?

Comment: Exatamente, a cada cadastrar no form, novas linhas com nome, telefone e e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como serão vários registros compostos por nome, telefone e e-mail, o que você precisa fazer é:

```php
$_SESSION["lista"][] = array(
    "nome" => $_GET["nome"],
    "telefone" => $_GET["telefone"],
    "email" => $_GET["email"]
);
```

Assim, cada item da sessão será um *array* com os três valores. Na hora de exibir, utilize o `foreach`, como já está fazendo, e acesse os valores com índices nomeados:

```php
$lista = $_SESSION["lista"];

<?php foreach($lista as $lis): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $lis["nome"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $lis["telefone"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $lis["email"] ?></td>
    </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Obrigado! funcionou e aprendi.